# phantomjs always times out when loading the page

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, phantomjs

I am trying to render my page through phantomjs 1.9. it's very basic, nothing fancy there(no ajax calls or any heavy js work happens).
However, I can't get it work. Tried through the console and got the same problem.

Phantomjs test examples work fine.

If i check the error's output I see:

```
Error Output: Unable to load resource (#22URL:http://localhost:8715/9723ced8448e4370a0e3614c5810b36b/arterySignalR/negotiate?requestUrl=http://my.project/Default.aspx?startDate=2013/06/01&endDate=2014/05/31&browserName=PhantomJS&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1401190054260)
Error code: 1. Description: Connection refused
```

Also tried to switch off signalR but still an issue.

Comment: Just curious if you have VS2013 and Browser Link on?

Comment: yes i use VS 2013 and browser link is on by default. so you think this is browser link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link in your Error log looks like the one from Browser Link's signalr. Even if you exclude signalr from your page it won't help. So, if you have VS2013 with Browser Link enabled, try to turn it off.

I had a similar issue in my team. Looks like phantomjs is waiting for the end of request from Browser Link's signalr instance. Check this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) how it works